# Html form isn't working

Tags: html, forms, thymeleaf

I have a form in my html, but it isn't working. How can I find the reason?

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="DoMakeApplication" method="post" id="my-form" onsubmit="alert('Başvurunuz alınmış ve yetkililere iletilecektir. Teşekkürler.');" >            
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.company.companyName}" name="companyName"  ></input>
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.company.id}" name="companyId"  ></input>
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${jobAdvert.id}" name="advertId" ></input>
    <button class="btn type7 color1" type="submit" id="makeApplication"   >Başvur</button>                                                      
</form>
```

Comment: Can you give us a jsFiddle link?

Comment: when i click the submit button, the form doesn't go to servlet

Comment: The js alert is triggered on submit action? Have you tried without it?

Comment: yeah i tried without it, still don't

Comment: I tried it in htmledit.squarefree.com. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what's the real problem, but try submitting the form by code using a button input:

```
<form action="DoMakeApplication" method="post" id="my-form">
....
<input type="button" value="Submit form" onclick="doSubmit()" />
....
</form>
```

And implement the javascript function:

```
function doSubmit(){
   document.getElementById("my-form").submit();
};
```

Hope it solves your problem ;)